# CyberSource API - Download Report - RESOURCE_NOTFOUND

Tags: cybersource

I'm using the CyberSource API to generate and download reports using the Postman collection.
The issue is when sending a "GET" request to download a report the following error coming back:

```
<errorBean>
    <code>RESOURCE_NOTFOUND</code>
    <detail>The requested resource is not found. Please try again later.</detail>
    <localizationKey>cybsapi.resource.notfound</localizationKey>
    <message>Requested Resource Not Found</message>
</errorBean>
```

Error when sending a request to download a report:
[image]

Success response when asking for the available reports on site:
[image]

I used the same environment variables for both requests.

Thanks,
Udi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I experienced a similar issue and had to log in to Cybersource EBC to configure the report subscriptions which were not carried over from the legacy system. It's likely that the error is caused because there is no report for the date you are requesting.

My understanding is that once you have configured the report subscriptions, Cybersource will start to create the report files as per the subscription - usually once daily. So you might only be able to request the report later in the day, or the following day.